When does a projection preserve right-handedness?
Let $p = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$ be a point in $\mathbb R^3$ which we wish to project to a point $q$ in $\mathbb R^2$.  We can do this via a $2 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $$q = Ap.$$
When does $A$ preserve right-handedness of the coordinate system? If $A$ were to be square, the answer is easy: when $\det A > 0$.  But for a $2 \times 3$ matrix, as used e.g. to project a scene onto a computer screen or paper, how do we determine this? How do we even define it?
For example, the projections below both preserve right-handedness:


Whereas if we swapped $x$ and $y$, the resulting projections would not.
Or, to put it numerically, the following projections preserve right-handedness:
$$
\begin{align*}
[1, 0, 0]^T &\to [0.7, -0.3]^T \\ 
[0,1,0]^T &\to [0.5, 0.5]^T \\
[0,0,1]^T &\to [0, 1]^T
\end{align*}$$
whereas the following do NOT:
$$
\begin{align*}
[1, 0, 0]^T &\to [0.5, 0.5]^T \\ 
[0,1,0]^T &\to [0.7, -0.3]^T \\
[0,0,1]^T &\to [0, 1]^T.
\end{align*}$$
This question is most relevant to two applications:

Computer graphics, which often assume right-handed coordinate systems
Plotting surfaces, which involves projecting the surface to $\mathbb R^2$ - different perspectives are allowed, but it is customary to make the plot right-handed (which is why the $x$ and $y$ axes are printed in textbooks in some configurations but not in others)

As an example, if you look at this diagram from Stewart:

the $x$ and $y$ axes are drawn flipped from where most beginners would naturally place them.  Most (all?) textbooks follow this convention.  I was told the reason was to preserve the right-handedness; switching $x$ and $y$ would eliminate that.

could you explain the projections in the figures? I cannot see them...

You need to specify the type of projection you are using. Also, it doesn't make sense to speak of "...preserve right-handedness of the coordinate system..." as $A$ is not an orthogonal matrix.

I have the strong feeling that the notion of "right-handedness preserving" does not make sense at all for maps between (oriented) vector spaces of different dimension. The standard definition (a map which transforms a positively oriented basis - i.e. right-handed - in a positively oriented basis) cannot be used and I think there is no meaningful extension. Could you provide a precise definition of what you mean?

@LGT It is a precise definition I'm looking for.  All textbooks assume the coordinate system looks like the ones I've shown.  Using software, for example, you can click and drag to rotate the system, but you can't switch positive $x$ and $y$ while keeping $z$ up.  How do we describe the restriction that imposes on $A$?

@Exodd I added a numerical example.  Graphically, if you consider the u
coordinate of your screen to get higher towards the right, and the v
coordinate of your screen to get higher towards the top, the place you see on your screen labelled "x" is the projection of $[1,0,0]^T$ to $\mathbb R^2$, the place you see on your screen labelled "y" is the projection of $[0,1,0]^T$, and the place labelled "z" is the projection of $[0,0,1]^T$.

The problem is subtle because there is, in my opinion, a psychological difficulty in distinguishing the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the geometry of objects of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are meant to represent three-dimensional objects.
Just as an example of this issue: consider the following image:

It is a well defined 2d object. However we are used to see it as a 2d representation of a 3-dimensional cube. The trouble is that there are two different ways of seeing it as a 3d object (what is the "top" face?...).
Now a specific answer to your question.
There is no reasonable way to define a "right-handedness preserving map" between oriented vector spaces of different dimensions.
In particular, there is no reason why, in your example, only the first projection has to be considered orientation preserving. A visual explanation, which is related to the issue of "clicking and dragging" in a software to move a coordinate system, is shown in the GIF below. We see that in fact it is possible to switch x and y while keeping z fixed.

The intuitive reason is the following: it is true that you cannot switch x and y while keeping z fixed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by performing orientation preserving transformations. However, you can switch the projections of x and y in $\mathbb{R}^2$ while keeping fixed the projection of z by performing orientation preserving transformations on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
In other words, given a projection $A\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and three linearly independent vectors $u,v,w\in \mathbb{R}^3$, there is no orientation preserving transformation $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into itself which swaps $u$ and $v$ while keeping fixed $w$, but there is an orientation preserving $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into itself such that $ARu=Av$, $ARv=Au$ and $ARw=Aw$. The easiest example is given by taking for $A$ the orthogonal projection on the $xy$ plane and for $R$ the transformation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by first rotating $180°$ around the $x$-axis and then $180°$ around the $z$-axis. If you take $u=(1,0,0)$, $v=(0,1,0)$ and $w=(1,1,1)$, you see that $Au=(1,0)$, $Av=(0,1)$ and $Aw=(1,1)$. After applying $R$, you get $Ru=v$, $Rv=u$ and $Rw=(1,1,-1)$ (hence you cannot actually swap $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ while keeping fixed $w$). However, when you project on the plane, you have $ARu=(0,1)$, $ARv=(1,0)$ and $ARw=(1,1)$.

Fascinating.  Thank you for exploring this.  I'm having trouble following the animation - can you please slow it down or add a pause button? (Or perhaps add some still frames showing the switch.)  I've also updated the question with a picture from Stewart.  Would you argue that his diagram would be just as correct if you switched the $x$ and $y$ axes?

A cue can be taken from virtual  mirror image physics. Plane and spherical mirrors have image lateral inversion and opposite sense handedness respectively. Hyperbolic mirrors preserve the sense of handedness.
